# Loading an XMI representation for MOF into EMF

Tags: eclipse, enterprise-architect, xmi

I'm working with Enterprise Architect. There it's possible to export your model as MOF 1.4/XMI 1.2 into a file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<XMI xmi.version="1.2" xmlns:Model="org.omg.xmi.namespace.Model" timestamp="2012-03-19 16:16:33">
<XMI.header>
    <XMI.documentation>
        <XMI.exporter>Enterprise Architect</XMI.exporter>
        <XMI.exporterVersion>5.1</XMI.exporterVersion>
    </XMI.documentation>
    <XMI.metamodel xmi.name="org.omg.mof.Model" xmi.version="1.4"/>
</XMI.header>
<XMI.content>
    <Model:Package name="MofModel" xmi.id="EAPK_E660ED7D_A77D_4721_B26B_E43EA754C0F1" isRoot="true" isLeaf="false" isAbstract="false" visibility="public_vis">
        <Model:Namespace.contents>
            <Model:Class name="Class2" xmi.id="EAID_425DBFFA_432F_4a43_B12B_DEF05643C5A3" isRoot="false" isLeaf="false" isAbstract="false" isSingleton="false" visibility="public_vis">
                <Model:GeneralizableElement.supertypes>
                    <Model:Class xmi.idref="EAID_E6FA2BB0_D81C_4b6c_86EF_9781887F5C26"/>
                </Model:GeneralizableElement.supertypes>
            </Model:Class>
            <Model:Package name="Package1" xmi.id="EAPK_F9D099B3_F646_4ca1_93CE_CBE09014C651" isRoot="true" isLeaf="false" isAbstract="false" visibility="public_vis">
                <Model:Namespace.contents>
                    <Model:Class name="Class1" xmi.id="EAID_E6FA2BB0_D81C_4b6c_86EF_9781887F5C26" isRoot="false" isLeaf="false" isAbstract="false" isSingleton="false" visibility="public_vis"/>
                </Model:Namespace.contents>
            </Model:Package>
        </Model:Namespace.contents>
    </Model:Package>
</XMI.content>
<XMI.extensions xmi.extender="Enterprise Architect 2.5"/>
```

After having this done, i want to load it in eclipse emf.
Until now, i found no possibility to do this.
Emf supports the XMI 2.0 standard (not 1.2). 
Is there something to convert to this version or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell EA to export in a wide range of XMI versions and other formats.

In the export dialog, click the Publish button and you should see a list with some dozen different XMI options.

Comment: Using EA 8, i have to right-click on the project and select "Export Model to XMI..." but there is no "Publish" present in that dialog.

Comment: Hmm, I don't remember what it looked like in EA8. I suggest you upgrade. EA is backwards-compatible wrt projects so you won't lose any information.